# Wordpress & Woocommerce - replace View Basket with Go To Checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I clik Add to Basket on product page I have this message on the screen:

> "Product Name" has been added to your basket.
>   ...and View Basket button/link next to it.

I want to change this button for 'Go to Checkout' button/link. Also, I don't want this change to be overwritten by future updates.

---

I found the line I need to change. It's inside wc_add_to_cart_message function (in wc-cart-functions.php).
There is an IF/ELSE statement and for success the message is:

```
$message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
```

I can change it here to:

```
$message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ) ), esc_html__( 'Go To Checkout', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
```

but I would like to do the same in functions.php

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can find more details [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/) you can add the following to your child-theme functions.php. If you don't have a child theme you would need to set one up to avoid your customizations being overwritten on updates.

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +

    function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {

    return __( 'My Button Text', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

Comment: I don't want to change text on Add to Cart button.
I want to change text and link on 'View Basket' button which is displayed when I click on Add to Cart.
View Basket should says Go to Checkout and be a link to checkout page

Comment: Hi, same principle but here is a more specific link http://sarathlal.com/change-proceed-to-checkout-text-in-woocommerce-cart-page/

Comment: I updated my question with more detail. Could you tell me the code I should put into functions.php ?